# Setup for env.development and env.production for vue3 project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I followed instructions to create a vite project for Vue3. The method I used did not create any env.development or env.production files, so I have little context reading the documentation. I'm guessing that I need something there, but what?

It compiles but fails on the router here:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter, RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";

const history = createWebHistory();
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Appointments",
    component: () => import("../views/Appointments.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/pets",
    name: "Appointments",
    component: () => import("../views/Pets.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/Claims",
    name: "Claims",
    component: () => import("../views/Claims.vue"),
  },
];
const router = createRouter({
  //fails on this line:
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
  
export default router;
```

How do I set base url?

Answer (score 0):

The `.env` files (including `.env.development`) must be manually added to your project directory. However, you don't need them to set `BASE_URL`, as `BASE_URL` is automatically set from the [`base` config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#base) in `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
         ? '/my/dev/baseurl/'
         : '/my/prod/baseurl/',
})
```

To reference environment variables in source, use `import.meta.env` instead of `process.env`:

```js
// createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL), ❌
createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL), ✅
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-base-url?file=vite.config.ts)

Comment: I have tried to copy your setup from that excellent demo, but I still don't have import.meta.env defined.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: I am using npm version 8.1.0. 

I guess I will try stack blitz and move my code there.