# navigation route after deploy project vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router4

after deployed my app (vue3 typescript) to local xampp folder ("test1"), the route does not work correctly. all routes redirect to "localhost/" not to the folder project "localhost/test1" ,
in vite.config.ts add base role to "test1". but have the same issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The .env files (including .env.development) must be manually added to your project directory. However, you don't need them to set BASE_URL, as BASE_URL is automatically set from the base config in vite.config.js or vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
         ? '/my/dev/baseurl/'
         : '/my/prod/baseurl/',
})
```

To reference environment variables in source, use import.meta.env instead of process.env:

```
// createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL), ❌
createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL), ✅
```

after that must to add in router/index

```
...
 history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
...
```

the original answer at [Setup for env.development and env.production for vue3 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948633/setup-for-env-development-and-env-production-for-vue3-project)